# Image is not sent by the client?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, networking, send

Before I go on, let me say that I searched in the Internet and here for an answer but I couldn't find any. My problem is my client doesn't send my image, both is just a piece of code.
Here is the client code:

```
ok=False
import sys
import socket
import pickle
import os
import time
import getpass
from passlib.hash import pbkdf2_sha256
global x
usern=getpass.getuser()
x=0
password1=False
password2=None
path="C:/Users/"+usern+"/Desktop/pictures/"
curdir=os.getcwd()
print(curdir)
host="192.168.178.62"
port=5002


def Help():                     #help part
    print("Help Menue")
    print("-----------")
    print("")
    print("Add picture:")
    print("Add a picture to the Databank")
    print("The picture should be a picture from a persons Face how can enter without warning")
    print("Every person how is not in the Dantabank will create an alarm message ")
    print("If you use it the first time the program create a picture folder for all pictures.")
    print("If you want to add a picture put it in this folder and run Addpicture")
    print("Pleas name the pictures like the person who is on the picture ")
    print("")
    print("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("Delete picture")
    print("Here you can delete pictures of the Databank so every persons Face you delete will not enter without a alarm message")
    print("")
    print("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("Add mail Address:")
    print("This option allows you to add a mail address were the alarm message is going to you can add so many as you like but max 50")
    print("")
    print("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("For Help:")
    print("Open this Help menu")
    print("")
    print("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("Logout:")
    print("That I don't explain")
    t=input("Press a button to exit: ")
    if t=="":
        print("")
        print("")
        main()


def delpic():                       #the function for delete a picture
    s=socket.socket()
    try:
        s.connect((host, port))
    except socket.error:
        print("")
        print("Could not connect to the server")
        print("")
        main()
    s.send(str.encode("Del"))
    direList=s.recv(2400)
    print("Here are the picture names:" + direList.decode("utf-8"))
    if direList=="Nothing in this Directory!":
        print("")
        main()
    delete=input("Which picture do you want to delete: ")
    if delete=="q":
        print("")
        main()
    s.send(str.encode("delete"))
    ok=s.recv(1024)
    if ok=="True":
        print("Picture is Deleted")
        o=input("Do you want to continue? [y/n]")
        if o=="y":
            delpic()
        else:
            main()
    else:
        print("Something goes wrong")
        print("")
        main()






def addpic():           #the add Picture function
    global host
    global port
    print("Enter the name of the picture")
    print(" ")
    try:
        t=os.chdir(path)    #test if the dir exist
    except OSError:
        print("error")
        t=False
    if t==False:
        os.chdir("C:/Users/"+usern+"/Desktop")
        os.mkdir("pictures")
        print(os.getcwd())
    print(os.getcwd())
    picname=input("Enter the picture name: ")
    try:
        os.chdir(path)
        os.path.isfile(picname)
    except( FileExistsError, FileNotFoundError):
        print("The file could not found try it aggain")
        q=input("Do you want to continue? [y/n]")
        if q=="y":
            addpic()
        if q=="n":
            print("")
            main()

    print("Picture found, Data will send pls wait...")
    s=socket.socket()
    s.connect((host,port))
    try:
        s.send(str.encode("picture"))
        s.send(str.encode(picname))
        with open(picname,"rb") as f:
            chunk=f.read(1024)
            while chunk:
                s.send(chunk)
                chunk=f.read(1024)
                if not chunk:
                    f.close()
    except socket.error:
        print("Could not connect to the server. Please check your Connection!")
    back=s.recv(1024)
    back=back.encode("utf-8")
    if back=="ok":
        print("Image has been successfully sent!")
    else:
        print("image was not sent!")
        print("Check your Connection")
    m=input("Do you want to continue? [y/n]")
    if m=="y":
        addpic()
    if m=="n":
        print("")
        print("")
        main()




def main():         #main part with options
    global user
    global passw
    print("1:Add picture")
    print("2:Delete picture")
    print("3:Add mail Address")
    print("4:For help")
    print("5:For logout")
    wish=int(input("What do you want to do?: "))
    if wish==1:
        addpic()
    if wish==2:
        delpic()
    if wish==3:
        addmail()
    if wish==4:
        Help()
    if wish==5:
        time.sleep(1)
        sys.exit()
        exit()
    if (KeyboardInterrupt, ValueError, Exception):
        print("")
        main()



def create():                           #the function were the user add his information
    global password1
    global password2
    global hash
    global host
    global port
    Pass_ok=False   #add all important infos
    user=input("Create a Username: ")
    print("Welcome "+user)
    username=open("username.pkl", "wb")
    save=pickle.dump(user,username)
    while password1!=password2:
        password1=input("Enter your Password: ")
        password2=input("Confirm your Password: ")
        Pass_ok=True

    if Pass_ok:
        hash = pbkdf2_sha256.encrypt(password2, rounds=200000, salt_size=16)
        password=open("pass.pkl","wb")
        save2=pickle.dump(hash, password)


    mail=input("Enter your Mail adress:")   #more important infos
    key=input("Enter your Instapush appid: ")
    secrect=input("Enter your Instapush secret: ")
    password=open("pass.pkl","wb")
    mail2=open("mail.txt","wb")
    key2=open("Key.pkl","wb")
    save3=pickle.dump(mail,mail2)
    username.close()
    password.close()
    s=socket.socket()
    s.connect((host,port))
    mail=open("mail.txt","rb")
    chunk=mail.read(1024)
    s.send(str.encode("mail"))
    while chunk:                    #this function should send the Mail.txt content
        s.send(chunk)
        chunk=mail.read(1024)
        if not chunk():
            mail.close()
            break

    print("")
    main()




def login():    #is the login menu
    global x
    global hash
    while x!=3:
        Pass=input("Enter your Password: ")
        right=pbkdf2_sha256.verify(Pass, hash)
        if right==True:
            print("")
            print("Welcome back "+user)
            print("")
            main()

            if right==False:
                x=x+1

            if x==3:
                print("That goes Wrong...")
                exit()
                sys.exit()

try:
    hash=pickle.load(open("pass.pkl","rb"))               #this is the part were everything Load dont know if that is working
    user=pickle.load(open("username.pkl","rb"))
    mail=pickle.load(open("mail.txt","rb"))
    ok=True
except(FileExistsError, FileNotFoundError, EOFError):
    print("Loading Error")
    create()



if ok==True:    #check if all is working
    login()

else:
    print("Load error") # this is the error if the file can't Load
    exit()
    sys.exit()
```

This is the server code:

```
import os
import sys
import pickle
import socket
import time
mail_path="/home/pi/Desktop/Pi_Secure/mail"
picture_path="/home/pi/Desktop/Pi_Secure/picture"
Video_path="/home/pi/Desktop/Pi_Secure/video"
key_path="/home/pi/Desktop/Pi_Secure/key"
main_path="/home/pi/Pi_Secure"
host="192.168.178.45"
port= 5001
s=socket.socket()
s.bind((host, port))



print("Server is online at "+host+":"+str(port))

def get_data():
    global host
    global port
    global picture_path
    global Video_path
    global key_path
    name=None
    s.listen(1)
    c ,addr=s.accept()
    print("Connection established to"+str(addr))
    data=c.recv(1024)
    data=data.decode("utf-8")
    dataMessage=data.split(" ", 1)  #split data in command a picture or text Document
    command=dataMessage[0]

    if command=="mail":
        os.chdir(mail_path)
        mail=open(mail_path,"wb")
        Mail=c.recv(1024)
        while Mail:
            mail.write(Mail)
            Mail=c.recv(1024)
            if not mail:
                mail.close()
                break





    if command=="key":
        os.chdir(key_path)
        key=open(key_path,"wb")
        Key=c.recv(1024)
        while Key:
            key.write(Key)
            Key=c.recv(1024)
            if not key:
                key.close()
                break


    if command=="picture":
        os.chdir(picture_path)
        picture=open(picture_path,"wb")
        pic=c.recv(1024)
        while pic:
            picture.write(pic)
            pic=c.recv(1024)
            if not pic:
                c.send("ok")
                picture.close()
                break



    if command=="Del":
        try:
            t=os.listdir()
        except OSError:
            t="Nothing is in this Directory"
            o=t,encode("utf-8")
            c.send(o)
            c.close()
        o=t.encode("utf-8")
        c.send(o)
        pickname=c.recv(1024)
        Picture=pickname.decode("utf-8")
        os.remove(Picture)
        c.send(str.encode("True"))

while True:
    if os.path.exists(main_path):      #this should check that everything what is important be existent
        get_data()

if socket.error:
    get_data()

else:
    os.chdir("/home/pi/Desktop")
    os.mkdir("Pi_Secure")
    os.chdir("/home/pi/Desktop/Pi_Secure/")
    os.mkdir("pictures")
    os.mkdir("mail")
    os.mkdir("key")
    get_data()


global c,addr
c.close()
```

Comment: Please fix your indentations

Comment: you read the file fully at first: `chunk=t.read()`. if you send the first chunk you send the whole file: the while loop is useless.

Comment: ok i fix that and test it

Comment: and an server error wait here is the full error:

Comment: File "/home/pi/Desktop/Pi_Secure/server.py", line 35, in get_data
    data=data.decode("utf-8")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 7: invalid start byte

Comment: @Flajt Can you update the existing code with the latest version ?

Comment: @DarthShadow ok done